# Does $ \mathfrak{A} \models (\exists x) \phi $ imply that $ \phi[x / t] $ for some term $ t $?

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

If $ \mathfrak{A} \models (\exists x) \phi $, does it mean that $ \mathfrak{A} \models \phi[x / t] $ for some term $ t $?

I think that the answer is ‘yes’. After all, it is sufficient to let $ t = x $.

Am I wrong?

---

Generally, it is not true. It is true if $\mathfrak{A} $ contains such closed term $t$ ( function symbol) that $[t]^\mathfrak{A} =d  $ where $ (\mathfrak{A}, \delta) \models \exists x \phi, \delta(x) =d$

Yeah?

---

EDIT : for Berrick Caleb Fillmore
@Berrick Caleb Fillmore, you said that

> No matter ow you assign an element of || to each variable, you’re
>   going to get all  or all . In general, the truth value of a
>   sentence (i.e., its validity in the model $\mathfrak{A}$) is
>   independent of your choice of valuation, because there aren’t any free
>   variables that could possibly cause the truth value to fluctuate.

So, let's see how I reasoning about it
Let $\phi = \exists x p(x)$ . Let $\mathfrak{A} = (A, \Sigma^f, \Sigma^r) $ be a model for $\phi$. $A = \{1,2\}, \Sigma^f = \emptyset, \Sigma^r = \{p(1)\}$
Let $\delta_1 (x) = 1, \delta_2 (x) = 2$.

Now, we see that $(\mathfrak{A}, \delta_1) $ satisfies $\phi$ and $(\mathfrak{A}, \delta_2) $ satisfies $\phi$ doesn't. So it does mean that it **depends on valutaion**.

Please help me understand where I am wrong- I know that you are right, of course.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: If by "term" you mean "closed term in the language of the associated theory" then no.  For example, in the theory of fields, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \models \exists x \, x^2 - 2 = 0$ but neither $\sqrt{2}$ nor $-\sqrt{2}$ can be expressed as closed terms in the language of fields.

Comment: There might not be a term, definable in the first-order language of the theory under consideration, that explicitly witnesses $ \phi $.

Comment: Another example comes from the Axiom of Choice. It posits the existence of a choice function for a collection of disjoint non-empty sets, but in most cases, one cannot define the choice function in explicit terms.

Comment: If you want to avoid variable *assignment* functions $s : \text {Var} \to |\mathfrak A|$ (see Enderton's textbook) you have to consider adding to the language new "names" (i.e. *constants*) for each $a \in |\mathfrak A|$ (see Shoenfield). In this way the semantical specifications are defined for *sentences* only (i.e. closed formulae) and thus $\mathfrak A \vDash \exists \phi$ **iff** $\mathfrak A \vDash \phi[\overline a/x]$, for some $a \in |\mathfrak A|$, where $\overline a$ is the "name" for the object $a$.

Comment: I don't understand. I have noted that variables are terms in the first order logic.

Comment: Yes, but $t$ can be a variable $x$... and thus we have first to define what means $\mathfrak A \vDash \phi(x)$.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by $\phi [t/x]$?

Comment: A variable is a term, but it isn’t a closed term. What you need for $ t $ to be is a term that is constructed from function symbols and constant symbols.

Comment: Ok, variable is not closed term. But why does it matter? "What you need for t to be is a term that is constructed from function symbols and constant symbols". Sure, what if there is no function symbol in $\mathfrak{A}$

Comment: If $ \mathfrak{A} $ has constant symbols but no function symbols, then $ t $ must be a constant symbol. If $ \mathfrak{A} $ has neither constant symbols nor function symbols, then you can’t find a $ t $ with the required property.

Comment: Is $A$ a model here, or a theory? In this case, it makes a significant difference.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't know. Probably it must be a model because I haven't hear about theory on my lecture. I have heared about model so it should be that.

Comment: @Logic: In your latest edit, what does $ \delta $ represent?

Comment: $\delta$ is a valuation function which satisfies $\exists x \phi$ in $\mathfrak{A}$

Comment: @Logic: I see. Actually, a valuation is a function $ \delta $, defined by induction on the complexity of formulas, from $ |\mathfrak{A}|^{\mathbb{N}} \times \operatorname{Form} $ to $ \{ \mathsf{T},\mathsf{F} \} $.

Comment: @Logic: As to why the existence of closed terms is necessary, a formula with a free variable generally cannot be assigned a truth value that is consistent with all possible valuations. Some valuations could yield $ \mathsf{T} $ while others could yield $ \mathsf{F} $. However, if all of the variables in a formula are bounded so that the formula is a **sentence**, then it has **only one** truth value for all possible valuations. Now, one way of turning a formula with free variables into a sentence is to replace each free variable by a closed term (if constant symbols are available).

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore, what do you mean by "However, if all of the variables in a formula are bounded so that the formula is a sentence, then it has only one truth value for all possible valuations".?  So, is my answer in the post right or not? Especially, what is **only one truth**?

Comment: @Logic: It still isn’t quite right. If the only free variable in $ \phi $ is $ x $, then $ (\exists x) \phi $ is a sentence. No matter how you assign an element of $ |\mathfrak{A}| $ to each variable, you’re going to get all $ \mathsf{T} $ or all $ \mathsf{F} $. In general, the truth value of a sentence (i.e., its validity in the model $ \mathfrak{A} $) is independent of your choice of valuation, because there aren’t any free variables that could possibly cause the truth value to fluctuate.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore thanks for your patience and your help hand :). Please note that I edited my post. And, moreover, please hint me how to improve my solution.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore, you said: "Actually, a valuation is a function $\delta$, defined by induction on the complexity of formulas, from $\mathfrak{A}^{\mathbb{N}} \times \text{ Form }$ to $\{,\}$" It is not true. A valuation is a function from $X \to A$ where $A$ is universum and $X$ is a set of variables.

Comment: @Logic: I call a function from $ \operatorname{Var} $ to $ |\mathfrak{A}| $ ‘an assignment’. It’s just that we’re using different terminology here.

Comment: @BerrickCalebFillmore, ok. So what do you mean by a valuation function ( not an assigment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to take care of the fine details of the semantical specifications ...

We can see :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA84) (2nd ed - 2001), page 84, for the definition of *variable assignement* function :

> $s : \text {Var} \to |\mathfrak A|$,

used to define what it means for $\mathfrak A$ to *satisfy* $\varphi$ with $s$ :

> > $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[s]$.

Informally, we have that $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[s]$ **iff** the interpretation of $\varphi$ determined by $\mathfrak A$, when to the free occurrences of the variable $x$ the "object" $s(x)$ is "assigned" as denotation, is true.

In this case, the obvious inductive clause for $\exists$ will be :

> $\mathfrak A \vDash \exists x \varphi [s]$ iff for some $d \in |\mathfrak A|$, we have $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi [s(x|d)]$,

where $s(x|d)$ is the function which is exactly like $s$ except for the fact that at the variable $x$ it assignes the value $d$.

Intuitively, a free variable $x$ acts a a pronoun of natural language: to assert e.g. "$x$ is red" il like to assert "it is red".

What is their meaning ? it depends on the context: if with "it" I'm pointing at my shirt, than the assertion is true. If instead I'm pointing at the book on the table, then the assertion is false.

The variable assignment function is a way to "formalize" the "context disambiguation" mechanism of natural language. Thus, the truth-value of "$x$ is red" depends on the denotation assigned to the variable $x$ by the function $s$.

---

We may have a different approach, where the semantical notions, like *true*, are defined only for *sentences*, i.e. *closed* formulae.

See : Joseph Shoenfield, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books/about/Mathematical_Logic.html?id=a9zuAAAAMAAJ) (1967), page 19.

In this case, we consider closed terms (i.e. "names" for the objects of the domain) and the semantical clause for $\exists x \phi$ amounts to considering a "substitutional instance" $\phi[t/x]$ for some closed term $t$.

For details, see also :

-George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=0LpsXQV2kXAC&pg=PA117) (4th ed - 2002), page 117 :

> Let us say that in the interpretation $\mathcal M$ the individual $m$ satisfies $F(x)$, and write
>
> > $\mathcal M \vDash F [m]$,
>
> to mean ‘if we considered the extended language $L \cup \{ c \}$ obtained by
>   adding a newconstant $c$ in to our given language $L$, and if among all the extensions of our given interpretation $\mathcal M$ to an interpretation of this extended language we considered the one $\mathcal M^c_m$ that assigns to $c$ the denotation $m$, then $F(c)$ would be true’:
>
> > $\mathcal M \vDash F[m]$ if and only if $\mathcal M^c_m \vDash F(c)$.

Comment: thanks for your patience. I'm reading Enderton's book but I cannot grasp what is the problem still. Especially you said: "You have to take care of the fine details of the semantical specifications". Where I don't take care of in my considerations? And in your last expression, did you mean $\exists $ instead of $\forall$?

Comment: @Logic - as per previous comments : (i) in your def (to avoid circularity : subst $x$ with $x$ itself) the term $t$ must be a *constant*; but (ii) the original language must not have enough (or at all) constants.

Comment: I get it. So we cannot assume that we have a constants in the language. But, why the term must be constant? Perhaps it comes from definition but I don't see it.

Comment: There is no problem. The $\phi(x)$ is just the same what $\phi$ is. So, $\phi$ is satisfable iff $\phi(x)$ is satisfable. And we know that exists such valutaion that $\phi$ and therefore $\phi(x)$ is satisfied.

Comment: @Logic - "why the term must be constant?" Correct : it must be a *closed* term, i.e. a "name" for some object of the domain. In the first-order lang of arithmetic, the only constant is $0$ but closed terms are all the *numerals* : $0, S(0), S(S(0)), \ldots$ as well as "more complex" one, like e.f. $S(0)+S(0)$. In this case (see Computability & Logic) the naive subst approach to quantification will work, because we have a name for each object of the domain $\mathbb N$.

Comment: thanks! Now it is more clear! :). Am I right that last approach  ( from Computability and Logic book) is similar ( perhpas equivalent ) to the one with a variable assigment function?

Comment: @Logic - yes, the two approaches are equivalent in the sense that they "validate" the same formulae. The basic difference is "philosophical" : For Comp & Logic only *sentences* have meaning; thus an open formula is only an "unsaturated" expression devoi of meaning. With Enderton, open formulae have "meaning in context" with the variable assignment device.